# MVC Routing vs Angular Routing: Is not enough with just MVC Routing?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

As far as I know the hash symbol(#) is the key when implementing routing in Angular. The web server only takes care about the part of the URL which is before the hash, and Angular takes care of the rest.

I´ve read some articles that explain how to remove the hash from URL. But if I remove the hash(#) from URL: Which routing works first?

OK, it is MVC. In that case we have to edit the MVC Route in order the server to understand the URL. But we are at the beginning again. Does it make any sense to use Angular Routing and MVC together ? Is not enough with MVC Routing?

Maybe I´m missing something. I hope you can help me.

Comment: The primary use for Angular is SPA. it is orthogonal to server-side routing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it make any sense to use Angular Routing and MVC together ? Is
>   not enough with MVC Routing?

**TL;DR;**

I've rarely use both. The only time I use both is when I need to authenticate the user for some routes.

**Long answer**

**1.** Authentication

As you already figured out, Angular routing is great when you want to navigate to another page without the roundtrip to the server. It's usually a SPA. But there might be a scenario when you need to authenticate the user before sending the HTML, then MVC routing will be handy. I wrote an [answer about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40800938/4949005). Note the difference between sending HTML and sending DATA to to the client. If you have no server routes the html-pages (or templates) will be fully accessible (unless you limit access in web.config or some other way). Some times the HTML-pages can contain some sensitive information as well...

The most common scenario is if you have a public site with an admin-part. But in my experience you can handle this on client side with client-side-routing only. It's usually the data that is sensitive, not the templates.

**2.** Server-side logging

The other scenario is when you want to do some logging on server side. For example if you want to log every page request. This can often be done on the client as well... Look at Google Analytics. But you might want to log the request even if the browser has javascript turned off.

**3.** SEO

There [*might* be some SEO-issues](https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2013/07/10-very-good-reasons-to-stop-using-javascript/) when using client-side-routing. But this is only when we render the html with client side templates and if we compare to completely rendered views with MVC.Net. Do not confuse me posting the link with me actually agreeing with the content...

**4.** WCAG

In my country all government sites need to follow [WCAG](https://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/wcag). One of the rules are - **no javascript**. Or at least that the site should be fully accessible without javascript. Without javascript client-side-routes are simply *very difficult*. ;)

These are some examples when you might need both server-side and client-side routes. **But to sum up, in most cases client-side is enough.**